# How do I get the modification time of a file that is uploaded to my Flask app?

Tags: python, flask, file-upload, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm building a Flask app in which users can upload files and information is extracted.

The modification time of the file is important for me because it tells when an event happened as the event time is not stored in the contents of the file.

Here is the html code I am using for the file upload, and the Python code to iterate over the files uploaded.

I am trying to read the modification time as the file is uploaded, then change the modification time of the file after it is saved, but it just saves the modification time of the copied file (just the current time).

I'm trying to get the modification time of the file as it exists on the user's computer.

```html
<div class="row justify-content-end">
   <input type="file" name="folder" webkitdirectory directory multiple>
</div>
<div class="row justify-content-end">
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="">Import</button>
</div>
```

```
file_path = os.path.join('upload\\', str(current_user.id), 'gamelogs', filename)
i.save(file_path)
original_mtime = os.path.getmtime(file_path)
os.utime(file_path,(original_mtime,original_mtime))
```

If there is an alternative method to uploading files to my Flask app that would preserve modification time, I would be open to it.